# Localhost sites under Team Foundation Server source control

Tags: git, tfs, localhost

I have installed TFS(with Git repository) recently. However I don't know how can I put localhost web applications under source control. Since for other projects like windows applications I just copy the app folder in local repository of the team project and then everything works fine but it doesn't work for localhost apps.
How can I put localhost apps under TFS 2015 source control? Should I change IIS settings? or any other settings?

I created a new  web project and copied all folders of localhost app in the project and copied the project solution in source control but when it builds the app it doesn't recognize the refrences , all bins and dlls and namespaces. What can I do?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide detailed steps? With Git repository, you need to add and then commit the changes and then push them to source control. And are you building Asp.Net project, did you run nuget restore before build?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't build your web application successful. To build solution using Team Build, we need to ensure that **on TFS Build agent , the Team Build Service can find the required dlls.**

For your scenario, I think you have three way to resolve this issue:

1.Create a Assemblies folder under Solution, and add all your dlls in this folder. After we check in the solution into TFS, the TFS Build Service will get the solution from TFS to build on the Build agent, in this case, the Assemblies folder under solution will be get together. (not recommend) The structure like this:

```
      TeamProject
                /Solution1
         /Assemblies
         /Poject1
         /Poject2
         /…
                /Solution2
                …
```

2.Create the same common folder on the Build machine as you created on your client, and the folder path is same. So when the TFS Build to build the solution on build agent it will try to find the dlls on the Build machine follow the relative path which your set in your project. (not recommend)

3.Using NuGet to manager your packages. On the build definition you just need to restore NuGet packages and will get all the required dlls. (recommend)

Additionally, to make the build successful, we should ensure the following things:

1. The solution can be built completely on Build machine using VS.
2. Ensure the your TFS Build Service account have the permission to
   build this solution on the Build machine.
3. Ensure the solution can be built completely on Build machine using
   MS Build.